# Probabilistic interpretation of derivative of a Dirac delta function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, probability-distributions

Consider $g : \mathbb{R}^d \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ defines some surface $\Sigma$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then I can define a random variable $X_1$ with support only on $\Sigma$ by using a pdf of the form $$p_1(x) := f_1(x) \delta(g(x)).$$  Then using that $u\delta(u) = 0$ we can see that the expectation of the constraint function is identically zero, $$\mathbb{E}[g(X_1)] = 0,$$ which I take to be a consequence of the fact that the pdf has no support outside of this surface.

To analyse further I'm going to restrict to $g(x) = x^2 - a^2,$ and I'm going to use polar coordinates with $r \in (0,\infty), \Omega \in S^{d-1}$. Then $\delta(g(x)) = \frac{1}{2a} \delta(r-a)$, and I can calculate the normalisation of the distrubution by $$\int dx p_1(x) = \frac{a^{d-2}}{2} \int_\Sigma d\Omega f_1(a,\Omega). $$ I believe that it's necessary for this integral to exist for $p_1$ to be a valid pdf defined on $\Sigma$. (I have a basic question at this point which is; is this also a sufficient condition for $p_1$ to be a pdf?)

What I want to try and understand is whether $$p_2(x) := f_2(x) \delta'(g(x))$$ can be interpreted as the pdf of some random variable $X_2$, or if not then whether it has some other kind of probabilistic interpretation.

I've spent some time looking into this by using the same steps as I did with $p_1$. This time I'll look at the normalisation first. I again restrict to $\Sigma$ a sphere as above, and I find that $$\int dx p_2(x) = -(d-2)\frac{a^{d-4}}{4} \int_\Sigma d\Omega f_2(a,\Omega) -\frac{a^{d-3}}{4} \int_\Sigma d\Omega \partial_r f_2(r,\Omega)\Bigg|_{r=a}. $$So, it seems relevant to try to understand whether this integral exists or not for a given $f_2$, which is something I don't know how to say very much about. Is it fair to say that if both of these integrals exist then I can normalise by dividing through by this quantity, and hence I can interpret $p_2$ as the pdf of some $X_2?$ Also my real usage case has $\Sigma$ non-compact, which I think is likely to be relevant.

Now I take a look at the expecation of the constraint, and I see that $\mathbb{E}[g(X_2)]$ is no longer equal to zero identically. Using $u\delta'(u) = -\delta(u)$ I find that on the sphere $$\mathbb{E}[g(X_2)] = -\frac{a^{d-2}}{2} \int_\Sigma d\Omega f_2(a,\Omega).$$ Following from my argument above that the vanishing of this expectation value was a consequence of the fact that $p_1$ had support only on $\Sigma$, this appears to me to imply that if $p_2$ can be interpreted as the pdf of a distribution, then this distribution now has support away from $\Sigma.$

So here are my questions;

- Can I somehow interpret $p_2$ as the pdf of a random variable $X_2$? If $\Sigma$ is non-compact, does this give some additional conditions on $f_2$?
- If this is the case, how is this pdf related to the surface $\Sigma$? Should I intepret that the pdf has support away from $\Sigma$ given that $\mathbb{E}[g(X_2)] \neq 0?$
- If this is not the case, is there some other kind of natural quantity in probability theory other than a pdf which I can interpret $p_2$ as being, and how would this quantity be related to $\Sigma$?

Comment: Your terminology seems to be a little bit strange (at least to me). What is the "pdf" $f_1(x) \delta(g(x))$? I think your intention is do define a pdf on $\Sigma$. But what is then the meaning of $\delta'$?

Comment: Yes, to my understanding $f_1(x) \delta(g(x))$ can be used as the pdf for a random variable which is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ but which has support only on $\Sigma$. The prime is just a derivative, so $\delta'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \delta(x)$

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a probability distribution that can be represented entirely by the derivative of a delta function, however, if you allow for multiple derivatives, it can be done as follows.$^\ast$

For simplicity, let me take the case $n=1$ of a probability distribution function $p(x)$ of the variable $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Assume that the distribution is fully determined by its moments $m_k=\int x^kp(x)\,dx$. Then $p(x)$ can be represented as a series of $k$'th derivatives $\delta^{(k)}(x)=d^k\delta(x)/dx^k$ of the delta function,
$$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{m_k}{k!}\delta^{(k)}(x).$$

<sub>Check that the moments match by computing
$$\int x^q \delta^{(k)}(x)\,dx=(-1)^k \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}x^q=(-1)^k k!\,\delta_{kq}.$$</sub>

$^\ast$A. Khuri, [Applications of Dirac's delta function in statistics](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00207390310001638313).

Comment: The right-hand side, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{m_k}{k!}\delta^{(k)}$, of your main identity is not even a Schwartz distribution on $\mathbb R$; on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, it is $0$. How can it then coincide with the function $p\in L^1(\mathbb R)$?